# Widgets under For loop not rendering in flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, dart

I am building a points calculator application in flutter. I used drop down button for user to select number of players. and I used for loop to create number of textformfield for user to fill the names of the player. When I perform hot reload, I can see the dropdown menu is working fine but the code under for loop is not rendering. Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewGame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewGameState createState() => _NewGameState();
}

class _NewGameState extends State<NewGame> {
  int? numberOfPlayers = 4;
  var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("New Game"),
        ),
        body: Row(children: [
          Container(
            height: 20,
            width: 300,
            child: Text(
              "enter the number of players",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DropdownButton<int>(
              hint: Text("Pick"),
              value: numberOfPlayers,
              items: <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map((int value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value.toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (int? newVal) {
                setState(() {
                  numberOfPlayers = (newVal);
                  if (newVal != 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < ((newVal as int) - 1); i++) {
                      String stringI = i.toString();
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: 'Enter player ' + stringI + 'name'),
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Please enter some text';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  }
                });
              })
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListView.builder`

My dirty-answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
//         body: Center(
        body: NewGame(),
//         ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewGame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewGameState createState() => _NewGameState();
}

class _NewGameState extends State<NewGame> {
  int? numberOfPlayers = 4;
  var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  // List<Widget> dd = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("New Game"),
        ),
        body: Row(children: [
          Container(
            height: 20,
            width: 300,
            child: Text(
              "enter the number of players",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.deepPurple,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DropdownButton<int>(
              hint: Text("Pick"),
              value: numberOfPlayers,
              items: <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map((int value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value.toString()),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (int? newVal) {
                setState(() {
                  print(newVal);
                  numberOfPlayers = newVal;
                });
              }),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: numberOfPlayers,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return makeTextInput();
                  }))
        ]));
  }

  TextFormField makeTextInput() {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(), labelText: 'Enter player name'),
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter some text';
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT** to make original answer work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: NewGame(),
    );
  }
}

class NewGame extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewGameState createState() => _NewGameState();
}

class _NewGameState extends State<NewGame> {
  int? numberOfPlayers = 4;
  var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  List<Widget> data = []; // <-- nothing here so nothing will be placed inside column
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("New Game"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(children: [
            Container(
              height: 30,
              width: 300,
              child: Text(
                "enter the number of players",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DropdownButton<int>(
                hint: Text("Pick"),
                value: numberOfPlayers,
                items: <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map((int value) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                    value: value,
                    child: new Text(value.toString()),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (int? newVal) {
                  data = []; // <-- it is need to be reset becasue you will end with adding more and more items
                  setState(() {
                    numberOfPlayers = (newVal);
                    if (newVal != 0) {
                      for (var i = 0; i < ((newVal as int)); i++) {
                        String stringI = i.toString();
                        data.add(createTextField(
                            stringI)); // <--here when magic happens.
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }),
            Column( // column is now attached to widget tree from begining. You only need to update items inside
              children:
                  data, //when data is changes, column is forced to rebuild
            )
          ]),
        ));
  }
}

Widget createTextField(String stringI) {
  // its return only TextField
  return Center(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Enter player ${int.parse(stringI) + 1} name'),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: So basically I needed to use list view builder rather than for loop. Can you please tell me the reason that my code was not working? thanks a LOT!

Comment: Because this column is not attached to anything. You build column with items but it lives in space ;) - column is not descendant for any widget

Comment: Now I need to pass all the player's name to next widget screen and create a table with players name 1st row of the table.. What should I do?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: I know the navigation process but what I meant was the data variable you used was used to store only the textform field. It stores the number of text form fields selected from the drop down button. now I need a method to store the values of each textform fields into a list variable when i click a submit button so that I can pass the list to another widget and access its data.

Comment: Use then TextInputController

Answer (score 1):

I'll distill and refactor your code to try to make it clearer why your code doesn't do what you intend:

```dart
class _NewGameState extends State<NewGame> {
  // ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // ...
      body: Row(
        children: [
          // ...
          DropdownButton<int>(
            // ...
            onChanged: onChanged,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onChanged(int? newVal) {
    void setStateCallback() {
      // ...
      for (var i = 0; i < ((newVal as int) - 1); i++) {
        // ...
        Column(
          children: [
            // ...
          ],
        );
      }
    }

    setState(setStateCallback);
  }
}
```

You can see that `setStateCallback` creates a `Column` object on each iteration but *never does anything with it*, and there's no way for those widgets to be returned from `setStateCallback` to be included in the widget tree returned by `build`.

One way (but not necessarily the best way) to fix it would be to add a `List<Column>` member to your `_NewGameState`, make your `setState` callback explicitly add `Column`s to that list, and then make your `build` method include that list somewhere.  I don't know exactly where in your widget tree you intend for those `Column` widgets to go, but, for example:

```dart
class _NewGameState extends State<NewGame> {
  // ...

  final columns = <Column>[]; // <--

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // ...
      body: Row(
        children: [
          // ...
          DropdownButton<int>(
            // ...
            onChanged: (int? newVal) {
              setState(setStateCallback);
            },
          ),
          ...columns, // <--
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onChanged(int? newVal) {
    void setStateCallback() {
      // ...
      columns.clear(); // <--
      for (var i = 0; i < ((newVal as int) - 1); i++) {
        // ...
        columns.add( // <--
          Column(
            children: [
              // ...
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    setState(setStateCallback);
  }
}
```